# Purpose of breadboard "studs" on base off micro breadboards?

Tags: breadboard

I recently bought some micro breadboards on Ebay.  Extremely useful little things.  However each have two awkward studs on their bases.  See the attached photo.   What I'm curious about is their purpose?  What might these "plugin" to or be used for?  I think I'm going to file them off.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They connect to a base that fixes them with regards to each other.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful image! Never seen such a thing before. E-Lego! :-)

Comment: @LorenzoDonati  I wonder, can these plug into the *bona fide* Lego(R) bricks?

Comment: Where have these been all my life?!

Comment: @NickAlexeev I *NEED* the datasheet of those puppies! :-D Too bad these came out now that SMT rules the world! BTW from what I can see from that photo they actually *could* be Lego(TM) "compatible" :-D

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that these things are part of a system that includes a baseboard that the studs on your part can snap into, so you won't have the individual pieces sliding around the desk.